how can I integrate web socket to next.js and nest.js
Backend url uses http protocol; frontend url uses https protocol. My app is running but web socket is not running and throw cors error. I suppose, the reason is protocol but I am not sure. Why is web socket not running?
frontend entgration: (next.js)
const socket=io("wss://localhost:3001/")

backend configuration for web socket:(nest.js)
const server = http.createServer(app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance());

  const io = new Server(server, {
      cors: {
          origin: '*', 
          methods: ["GET", "POST"],
          allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
      }
  });

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('a user connected');
      console.log({socket})
  });

For test, I defined * for origin but It didin't work.
I defined self-improved ssl but it is not good way. and chrome didn't give permission self-improved ssl.

Can you also share the cors error here?
